# C# audit overriding SaveChanges() method. How to find out foreign keys of an entity and its value from table

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, overriding

I m overriding the SaveChange() method. What i want is that to log all changes made to an entity to database in simple text like "abc updated Name john to doe, ..." etc
I have achieved the functionality but when there is a foreign key in an entity going to update like country_Id which points out the table Country it generates text like  "abc updated Country_Id 1 to 3, ..." thats what I do not want it should be like this "abc updated Country Canada to Australia, ..."

So to achieve this it should know the foreign keys and its value

My Code is :

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        List<string> listChanges = new List<string>();
        List<string> listTable = new List<string>();

        var objectStateManager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
        IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes =
            objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted);


        foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntryEntity in changes)
        {

            var modifiedProperties = stateEntryEntity.GetModifiedProperties();
            foreach (var propName in modifiedProperties)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(stateEntryEntity.OriginalValues[propName]) != Convert.ToString(stateEntryEntity.CurrentValues[propName]))
                {
                    listTable.Add(stateEntryEntity.EntityKey.EntitySetName);
                    listChanges.Add(propName + " From " + Convert.ToString(stateEntryEntity.OriginalValues[propName]) + " to " + Convert.ToString(stateEntryEntity.CurrentValues[propName]));

                }


                //System.Console.WriteLine("Property {0} changed from {1} to {2}",
                //     propName,
                //     stateEntryEntity.OriginalValues[propName],
                //     stateEntryEntity.CurrentValues[propName]);
            }
        }
         return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: There is a project here that allows you to audit changes made by entity framework, new and old values etc.  I wonder if any of the code in there could help you to achieve this.  https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext  The problem that you've got is that often relationships like this, a foreign key, identifies an Id of an entire row, so you can't display 'Canada to Australia' without specifying the column name specifically... unless you adopt some kind of convention.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature to achieve this, i used changetracker for track changes and log.You get every changes right before dispose your context so, for briefly you can build like this;

```
public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            foreach (var history in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(e => e.Entity is IModificationHistory && (e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                                                                 e.State == EntityState.Modified))
                .Select(e => e.Entity as IModificationHistory)
            )
            {
                history.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
                if (history.DateCreated == DateTime.MinValue)
                    history.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            }
            var result = base.SaveChanges();
            foreach (var history in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(e => e.Entity is IModificationHistory)
                .Select(e => e.Entity as IModificationHistory)
            )
                history.IsDirty = false;
            return result;
        }
```

Also you can specify your entry right before base.savechanges()

This is my history interface

```
 public interface IModificationHistory
    {
        DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
        DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        bool IsDirty { get; set; }
    }
```